# Creating an array from vectors in a specific order

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have three vectors of different lengths X,Y,Z

for each combination (X(i),Y(j),Z(k)), I have computed a value C(i,j,k) = f(X(i),Y(j),Z(k)) which is a float.

I have stored these results in a matrix M which has 1 column and length(X)*length(Y)*length(Z) columns so that the results correspond to the computation in the following order: (eg with 2 elements for each vector)

```
[f(X(1) Y(1) Z(1))
f(X(1) Y(1) Z(2))
f(X(1) Y(2) Z(1))
f(X(1) Y(2) Z(2))
f(X(2) Y(1) Z(1))
f(X(2) Y(1) Z(2))
f(X(2) Y(2) Z(1))
f(X(2) Y(2) Z(2)]
```

How can I write the values of f(X(i),Y(j),Z(k)) in a 3D array T so that T(i,j,k)=f(X(i),Y(j),Z(k))? A for loop doesn't work for me because of the number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function do what you want?